# Custom "copy as Pathname" in Finder

Tags: finder, copy-paste

Is there a way to somehow customize "copy as Pathname" in Finder (write-click, option, ...) so that the pathname that is copied is modified (e.g. to replace my username with somebody else's)?

Comment: You would have to create a new Quick Action in Automator, rather than modifying the existing OS function. But just as easy to alter the text in a text editor before passing onto Terminal or whatever.

Comment: It's just as easy to replace everything before the user's folder with `~/` then the actual user name is unimportant. [In fact, I've often wish that was the default rather than the full path.]

Comment: Since I'm going to be doing this often, I'm looking for a way to automate the whole thing

Comment: Any tips on how to approach this with Automator?

Answer (score 2):

> Any tips on how to approach this with Automator?

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** and as an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes any necessary and or appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be used In **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* setting **Workflow receives current [files or folders] in [Finder]** and adding a **Run AppleScript** *action* replacing the default *code* with the *example* **AppleScript** *code* and setting the **Options** of the **Run AppleScript** *action* to: **[√] Ignore this action's input**

As currently coded you can set the `diffShortUserName` *variable* to whatever, it's currently `foobar`, or you can comment out the first line of *code* and uncomment the commented *block* of *code*, which will present a *dialog box* for you to enter a different *short user name* each time you use the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*.

This will place on the **clipboard** the **POSIX pathname** of any selected *files* or *folders* in the frontmost *window* of **Finder**, from anywhere in your **Home** *folder*.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set diffShortUserName to "foobar"

(*
set diffShortUserName to ""
repeat while diffShortUserName is ""
    set diffShortUserName to ¬
        text returned of (display dialog ¬
        "Different Short User Name:" default answer "")
end repeat
*)

tell application "Finder" to ¬
    set selectedFiles to ¬
        (selection as alias list)

set myShortUserName to short user name of (system info)
set selectedFilesCount to count selectedFiles
set thePathnamesList to {}

repeat with thisFile in selectedFiles
    
    set thePathname to the POSIX path of thisFile
    
    if thePathname contains "/Users/" & myShortUserName & "/" then
        
        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to ¬
            {AppleScript's text item delimiters, myShortUserName}
        set foo to text items of thePathname
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to diffShortUserName
        set thePathname to foo as string
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
        
        if selectedFilesCount is greater than 1 then
            copy thePathname & linefeed to end of thePathnamesList
        else
            copy thePathname to end of thePathnamesList
        end if
        
    end if
    
end repeat

set the clipboard to thePathnamesList as string
```

**Notes:**

If you are looking to replace your *short user name* that is elsewhere in the **POSIX pathname** of any selected *files* or *folders* in the frontmost *window* of **Finder** not in your **Home** *folder*, then additional coding will be necessary.

One can also assign a *keyboard shortcut* to the **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, however, some prefer to use a *third-party application* that is capable of running **AppleScript** *code* and assigning a *keyboard shortcut* to it.

As an example, I use [**FastScripts**](https://redsweater.com/fastscripts/) for some tasks, as well as [**Hammerspoon**](http://www.hammerspoon.org) for other tasks. (I am not associated with the developers of these products, just a satisfied user.)

This is also why I've coded it in the manner I did, removing the default *code* and setting the *option* in the *action* I did, as it makes the *example* **AppleScript** *code* available to work in the different methods in which it can be used.

---

[image: Automator Service Quick Action]

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Since a direct solution to your question was already provided, I figured I would offer an **alternate solution** which will also return the same results needed.

This following **AppleScript** was tested using the latest version of macOS Big Sur.

**First**, In Script Editor.app / Preferences, enable the **“Show Script menu in menu bar”** option as demonstrated in this following image.

[image]

Next, paste this following **AppleScript** code into a new Script Editor document and save it to the folder /Users/***Your_Short_Name***/Library/Scripts/Applications/Finder/

*If that folder does not exist, create it then save the script.  I named my version “Edit Short Name in Clipboard Paths.scpt“*

```
property newShortName : missing value

set selectedFilesPosPaths to {}

activate
-- using "words of..." and "...as text" removes any accidental leading or
-- trailing or other space characters typed (Short User Names have no spaces)
set newShortName to words of text returned of ¬
    (display dialog "Enter A User's Short Name In Lowercase & With No Spaces" default answer "") as text

tell application "System Events" to set usersDirectory to POSIX path of home folder

tell application "Finder" to set selectedFiles to selection as alias list

repeat with thisAliasPath in selectedFiles
    set end of selectedFilesPosPaths to ¬
        POSIX path of thisAliasPath
end repeat

set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to selectedFilesPosPaths as text

do shell script "pbpaste | sed " & "'s@" & usersDirectory & "@/Users/" & ¬
    newShortName & "@g' | pbcopy"
```

Now, anytime you are in Finder and you want to copy the file paths of the selected files in the frontmost Finder window and change the short user name of the paths on the clipboard… All you need to do is select the script menu in the menu bar and select your script. (as shown in the image below)

[image]